# My random integer only returns the same number

Tags: python

**I'm trying to run this code:**

```
import random
import time


random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)
time.sleep(.1)
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i)
    print("Random: ", random_int)
    time.sleep(random_int)
```

**But every time I run it, the random_int always returns the first number it chooses, so:**

```
1
Random:  4
2
Random:  4
3
Random:  4
4
Random:  4
5
Random:  4
6
Random:  4
7
Random:  4
8
Random:  4
9
Random:  4
10
Random:  4
```

Process finished with exit code 1

**Or:**

```
1
Random:  2
2
Random:  2
3
Random:  2
4
Random:  2
5
Random:  2
6
Random:  2
7
Random:  2
8
Random:  2
9
Random:  2
10
Random:  2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "I rolled a die and looked at it 100 times, and it said 4 every time!" Well, re-roll the die.

Comment: How many times are you calling `randrange` ? ;)

Comment: The [real](https://xkcd.com/221/) reason behind all this.

Comment: I'd understand if the "won't let me submit this question without more text so this is text" stuff was in the first revision, but you just *edited* that in after the earlier versions didn't have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer it because I've been in desperation before
Going off of @user2357112: 
You are storing random_int = random.randrange(1, 6) once 
 
The loop is effectively doing nothing but referencing the random_int you stored first. 
In order to have that change, you need to change the value in random_int, preferably by putting random_int = random.randrange(1, 6) inside the for loop, having it change every time.
I hope that clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the random function inside the loop

```
import random
import time


time.sleep(.1)
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i)
    random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)
    print("Random: ", random_int)
    time.sleep(random_int)
```

What you are doing is printing a variable `random_int` which has a value already assigned

Answer (score 0):

You have to "roll" your die:

```
import random
import time

time.sleep(.1)

for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i)
    random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)
    print("Random: ", random_int)
    time.sleep(random_int)
```

`randrange` generates a random, so, if you want to generate a new one each time, you have to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occuring as the assigning line(4th line) is outside the loop.
You are basically assigning the random_int at first, then printing it again and again without changing the variable.

```
import random
import time

random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)
time.sleep(.1)
for i in range(1, 101):
    print(i)
    print("Random: ", random_int)
    time.sleep(random_int)
```

In order to fix the problem, bring 'random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)  ' inside the loop so it assigns the new value every single loops. Like this

```
import random
import time


time.sleep(.1)
for i in range(1, 101):
    random_int = random.randrange(1, 6)
    print(i)
    print("Random: ", random_int)
    time.sleep(random_int)
```